# How zsh zle prevent variable CURSOR to be modified arbitrarily in runtime?

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

As [the document](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#User_002dDefined-Widgets) says, the zle variable CURSOR can only be in range `[0, $#BUFFER]`.

Test code (put it into .zshrc, the `^[OP` is F1):

```sh
testCursor() {
  echo "\nOriginal C: $CURSOR"
  BUFFER="a"
  echo "Change Buffer: $CURSOR"
  CURSOR=$((CURSOR+10))
  echo "Force edit: $CURSOR"
  CURSOR=100
  echo "Force assign: $CURSOR"
}
zle -N testCursor
bindkey '^[OP' testCursor
```

[image]

The `CURSOR` satisfied it's range definition in runtime, how did the zsh-zle implements it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate. What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: As you can see, the valid range of CURSOR is dynamic. How can I make a variable value being constraint by another variable dynamically? I don't know any way to constraint the range of a variable, much less a dynamic constraint.

Comment: The only constraint I know is using `typeset` to make a variable integer/float, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CURSOR` value is handled in Zsh's source code, which is implemented in the C programming language: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3c93497eb701d8f220bc32d38e1f12bfb534c390/Src/Zle/zle_params.c#L266

There is no way for you to declare a similarly constrained variable in Zsh shell code.

However, you can write a math function for it instead:

```sh
# Declare a global integer.
typeset -gi TEST=0

# -H makes these hidden, that is, not listed automatically.
typeset -gHi _TEST_MIN=0 _TEST_MAX=10

# Load `min` and `max` functions.
autoload -Uz zmathfunc && zmathfunc

set_test() {
  (( TEST = min(max($1,$_TEST_MIN),$_TEST_MAX) ))
}

get_test() {
  return $(( min(max($TEST,$_TEST_MIN),$_TEST_MAX) ))
}

# Declare `set_test` as a math function accepting exactly one numeric argument.
functions -M set_test 1

# Declare `get_test` as a math function accepting exactly zero arguments.
functions -M get_test 0
```

You can then use these in arithmetic statements, with this syntax:

```sh
❯ print $(( get_test() ))
0

❯ (( set_test(100) ))

❯ print $(( get_test() ))
10
```

But also in other contexts, with this syntax:

```sh
❯ set_test -1

❯ get_test; print $?
0
```